# Change transcription name value for service console

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console

How can we change the chat transcription tab name to a more useful information (such as the visitor email or any other related custom field)?

[image]

The agents might find it challenging to find the proper conversation in a long list of open tabs...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the two approaches you can try as per your need:

**Approach #1**

In the console app, you could update the Navigation Rules to open the chat as a subtab of the related Contact or Account. Make sure the contact and account fields are not null on the chat transcript.

***Click path for setting up Navigation rules***:Setup> App Manager >Choose the Console App>Edit> Add "Chat Transcript" to "Navigation Items" > In Navigation Rules, choose "Chat Transcript opens As" either account/contact.

**below is screenshot highlighting chat transcripts opened as subtabs within contact tab for better identification**
[image: Screenshot highlighting chat transcripts opened as subtabs within contact tab for better identification]

**Approach #2**

Install the [package](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3h000004m8XY) ChangeTabLabel.The prerequisite to install the package is to [turn on Messaging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.livemessage_enable.htm&type=5) from the 'Messaging Settings'

Code is made available in GitHub:https://github.com/sf-kiwi-cpat/ChangeTabLabelComponent

The component in the package is designed for Console Apps and will update the tab of the workspace with more relevant information. For instance, the subject of the case, or a related Contact or Account for that record.

Currently, 4 object records are supported by this component:

- Case
- Chat Transcript
- Messaging Session
- Work Order

Steps to use this component:

1. Go to the record page (one of the 4 supported objects above) you wish to add this component to
2. Go to settings and select ‘Edit Page’
3. In the search box in the left-hand pane, type ‘change'and Drag the ‘*ChangeTabLabel*’ component onto the pane - make sure it is below any other component.
   The component itself has no UI, but it will create whitespace, so have it at the bottom of your shortest section.
4. If you just want to use the Contact or Account, then you are done. However, if you want to use a different field on the record (e.g. Subject for Case), then you can edit the setup of the component:
5. The ‘Use Contact or Account as priority’ allows you to define the ‘Field’ as a fallback, so if the Contact or Account isn’t found then it will use the value of the defined field as the label for the Tab.
6. Save and Activate the page.

Now when you open the record home page for the page you just updated, the tab will be updated to match the Contact or Account as appropriate.

It will even update when you save changes to the record!

Note: This is not on the AppExchange but can be installed. This package has been built by Salesforce development Engineers.No support is provided officially by Salesforce

Comment: @Bernardo Lira Let me know if you've been able to try out any of these and have any follow-up queries. Happy to help!

Comment: THANKS!! I'm trying the Approach #2, but "There are problems that prevent this package from being installed" bc "WorkOrder" is not present in the org (which is correct). Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: We have removed the code dependencies. Please use this new URL to install the package https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3h000004OQnJ

Comment: HI  Bernardo, Following up to see if you could successfully install the package and check the functionality.

Comment: Hi Swetha. Tried again with the new link but same error appears (WorkOrder object not present).

Comment: Here is the link https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3h000004OQnJ. Please note we're trying to install in Sandbox environment so we changed it to https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3h000004OQnJ

Comment: Can you please try the this new package link with updated code https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3h000004m8XY

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!